# What's the difference between "think in" and "sink in"?

Tags: word-usage

> Let that sink in a little …

I have never thought "sink" would have a meaning of "Understanding". At first, I thought maybe it was a type error. After looked it up, I see there does exist this usage.

Comment: *Sink in* is an idiomatic expression. And as is typically the case with idiomatic expressions, they are not to be understood literally. As for *think in*, there is no such expression in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sink in](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sink-in) is a very common figure of speech - the phrase "think in" is not colloquial at all.  **Sink in** doesn't just mean "understand," it means "a slow or reluctant process of understanding."

If you want to visualize it, imagine a very muddy or viscous pool of liquid. Objects will literally sink into this liquid very slowly. That is the metaphor here: the person's thinking is very thick and slow and it takes some time before understanding "sinks in" to their brain.